# How to use concurrent futures to web scrape faster? Selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to scrape a list of URLs with Selenium and concurrent futures to speed up the process. I've found that I get a StaleElementReferenceException when using concurrent futures, and also the job titles do not correspond to the URLs. For instance, I get repeated job titles. When using a normal "for" I do not get this error.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is welcomed.

My simplified code is:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
wd.maximize_window()

vurl = ['https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/asistente-contable-exp.-en-concar-ssp-1114585777.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/asesor-a-comercial-digital-de-seguro-vehicular-1114584904.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/mecanico-de-mantenimiento-arequipa-1114585709.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/almacenero-l.o.-electronics-s.a.c.-1114585629.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/analista-de-comunicaciones-ingles-avanzado-teleperformance-peru-s.a.c.-1114564863.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/vendedores-adn-retail-s.a.c.-1114585422.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/especialista-de-intervencion-de-proyectos-mondelez-international-1114585461.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/desarrollador-java-senior-inetum-peru-1114584840.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/practicante-legal-coes-sinac-1114584788.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/concurso-publico-n-143-especialista-en-presupuesto-banco-central-de-reserva-del-peru-1114584538.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/concurso-n-147-especialista-en-analisis-de-infraestructuras-financieras-banco-central-de-reserva-del-peru-1114584444.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/asistente-legal-magdalena-del-mar-los-portales-1114584305.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/asistente-de-nuevos-negocios-inmobiliarios-madrid-ingenieros-1114584269.html',
 'https://www.bumeran.com.pe/empleos/trabajo-desde-tres-horas-por-dia-ventas-ventas-por-internet-1114584205.html']


vtitle = []

def get_urls(url):
    wd.get(url)
    wd.implicitly_wait(20)
    try: 
        title = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//h1").text
        print('URL finished')
    except:
        title=''
        print('Exception!')
    vtitle.append(title)
    vurl2.append(url)

# This throws an exception and does not scrape correctly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
   executor.map(get_urls, vurl)

# output is for example
#['ALMACENERO', 'ALMACENERO', 'ALMACENERO', 'ALMACENERO', 'Desarrollador Java (Senior)', 'Desarrollador Java (Senior)', 'Desarrollador Java (Senior)']

# when it should be:
# ['ALMACENERO', 'Analista de Comunicaciones - Inglés Avanzado', 'Vendedores', 'Especialista de Intervención de Proyectos', 'Desarrollador Java (Senior)', 'Practicante Legal', 'Asistente Legal - Magdalena del Mar']


# This works fine but is too slow
for url in vurl:
    get_urls(url)
```

Comment: I thought people are reading basic rules of the forum before using it...

Comment: for multi-threading you need one driver/browser per thread.  (beware, browsers take up a lot of resources...)

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for the advice! So then I'd have to put `wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)` inside my function for threading to work?

Comment: build an array of initialized webdrivers... pass calls to each.